# fnAddData datatable 1.9 with State Save

Tags: datatable, datatables

I am adding data to my datatable using aaData.

I want to append more data to my datatable(after ajax call).

```
bill_ov_np.selected.table =  myid.dataTable({
                "aaData": data.rows,
                "iCookieDuration": 1,
                "aoColumns": data.columns,
                "bStateSave": true,

        "bFilter": false,
                "aaSorting": [[2 ,"desc"]],
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sZeroRecords": "<h5 class='text-info'>No Data available</h5>",
                     "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of " + display_total + " entries."
                },
                "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
                 "iDisplayLength" : 5



            });



        ****
```

**bill_ov_np.selected.table.fnAddData(data.rows,false);** 
This is what I am using to append data to my datatable.

I also want to store the state of my Datatable after adding data to it .
But it is not working, even tough I passed second parameter as false to the fnAddData method,Still after adding data to my datatable I am again coming back to the first page, which I don't want, If i Was on 3rd page then I want to be there even if data is being getting added to my datatable.

**I am using bstatesave property in my code**

Thank you very much.

Comment: The syntax which you used is perfect.No Issues with it

Comment: I also want to store state of my Datatable , but I am not able to save it .After hitting my ajax call and adding data to my datatable , I am returning to the first page again and I don't want , I want to stay on the page on which I clicked.

Comment: Is there any method other than fnAddData.
Now what I am doing is :


1. Initialize datatable with .datatable function.
2. after that I am checking if my datatable object is empty
3. if not then call fnAddData method.

But I am not able to save the state.

Comment: Use bStateSave property

Comment: yes I did that. you can see in my code but only works when I add data with aaData.
I have checked it. After Initializing my datatable if I add data using fnAddData then it is not working.

Comment: Sir do you know any way so that i can change the fnPagingInfo, so that I can directly save my settings. I have tried

fnPagingInfo.iPage = '3' to save my page number but this is also not working.

Thank you

Comment: I have edited my question and made it very general .I hope now you can help me out.